# np.nanmean of 500 large numpy matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to get the average(ignoring nan values) of very large bumpy matrices. I know I can load them in without taking up too much memory, doing something like :

```
X=np.load('my_matrix_1.npy', mmap_mode='r')
```

And then I can read some lines from it. I was thinking of reading 1000 line at a time from each matrix, and storing the nan mean of those in a matrix the size of, a

so something like this:

```
for chunk in chunks:
     chunk_to_mean = []
     for matrix in matrices:
          X=np.load(matrix, mmap_mode='r')
          chuck_to_mean.append(X)
          del X
     matrix[chunk] = np.nanmean(chunk_to_mean)
```

however, it seems that I get a memory allocation error after on the second time I try to load something with memory mapping, even if I delete it. Does anyone know how to solve this, or perhaps have a better idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This code has several problems. The first is that 
    chunk_to_mean = []
creates an array. However, you add the numpy arrays as elements to that array - so it becomes a list of numpy arrays, but np.nanmean does not take a list of arrays, but an np.array.

The second one is that you either have a dictionary, and you can address an array using a string, or you have a list, and then you have to use an int. So your `chunk[matrix]` does not make sense.

So you have two options. If all the chunks have the same size, you can take the np.nanmean for each matrix, and then the mean of the resulting list.

```
results = []
for chunk in chunks:
    chunk_to_mean = []
    for matrix in matrices:
        X=np.load(matrix, mmap_mode='r')
        chuck_to_mean.append(np.nanmean(X))
        del X # why do you need this?? This is python - it has garbage collection!
    results.append(np.nanmean(np.array(chunk_to_mean)))
```

The other option, if you want a weighted mean, is to concatenate the matrices, and then take the np.nanmean of that:

```
results = []
for chunk in chunks:
    for i in range(len(matrices)):
        X=np.load(matrix, mmap_mode='r')
        if i==1:
            all_matrices = np.array(X)
        else:
            np.concatenate((all_matrices, np.array(X), axis=0) # check the concat axis!!
        del X
    results.append(np.nanmean(all_matrices))
```

Comment: You have to del X because it will create a memory allocation problem if you try to memory map more than once without deleting the object, it seems. But, as I said, after the first iteration, on the second iteration, it fails and throws a memory error, not because it's out of memory, but because the memory can not be allocated. Thats why neither of those will work.

Comment: Ok - I think I have an idea on the problem. The point is that numpy arrays are mostly treated as pointers to arrays.  So when you append X you do not append the file, but a pointer to the file. To remedy this problem, copy the matrix first. A good way to do this with np. arrays is to `np.array(orig_pointer)` - this call will copy the data over, and you should be able to use all the np.* functionality.

Comment: I updated the second version to make a copy of X when concatenating (see the `np.array(X)` calls).

Answer (score 0):

This is tested and works. It should work on any a very very large matrix, as it is only reading in one row of the matrix at a time. As long as you can hold the average matrix in memory, it will run.

```
def average_subject_real(subject):
   matrix = np.load('graph_matrix_%s_1.npy' %(subject), mmap_mode = 'r')
   matrix_size = matrix.shape[0]
   del matrix
   average_matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size,matrix_size))
   for line in range(matrix_size):
       temp_array = []
       for i in range(1,5):
           matrix = np.load('graph_matrix_%s_%s.npy' %(subject,i), mmap_mode = 'r')
           matrix = np.array(matrix[line]) # the copying happens here
        temp_array.append(matrix)
        del matrix
        average_matrix[line] = np.nanmean(temp_array,axis=0)
    np.save('graph_matrix_%s_average.npy' %(subject),arr=average_matrix)
```

Comment: The problem I was having before is, as cleros pointed out, you have to copy the array or else the pointer still exists and you can't get a new memory mapped array object. Thanks so much for everyone's help, it's running now!